# Hey guys I am trying to call an api in vitejs(react) with axios get method but I am getting CORS error(XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, cors

The full error (Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular net::ERR_FAILED)

This config file for the axios

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
const TMDB_TOKEN = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_TMDB_TOKEN;

const headers = {
  Autherization: "bearer" + TMDB_TOKEN,
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  "Content-Type": "text/plain",
};

export const fetchDataFromApi = async (url, params) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(BASE_URL + url, {
      headers,
      params,
    });

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
};
```

And this is how I am calling the function in app.jsx

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiTesting();
  }, []);

  const apiTesting = () => {
    fetchDataFromApi("/movie/popular").then((res) => console.log(res));
  };
}
```

In Postman when I try to send the get request the response is there but in localhost this error occurs.

I tried to add the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" header and tried some cors extensions to bypass cors errors but still, the error occurs.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies) says to pass the api key as a url param and not in an authorization header

Comment: I was following a tutorial in which he used the same code and got the response, but when I tried, it gave me the CORS error. tutorial URL :- (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLgVw2NEqCM&t=2281s) timestamp 38.22

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what changed but it's best to check the api documentation. One thing different from your code and his code is that you used `"bearer"` instead of `"bearer "`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I tried adding that space after "bearer " but I don't think that's the issue here the error is related to CORS I guess

Answer (score 0):

I think the CORS error could be fixed from your API settings not in your React App. There needs to be a section to put your request server IP or domain name on your API settings, at least most APIs have one. CORS is mostly blocked by the backend side to protect the API from XSS attacks. Should you check the API management pages if you have any section to write your request server IP or domain name on it?

It might me the Application URL section that you need. It is asking while you are creating the API Application on your account.

[image]

Comment: I have already updated my localhost url there but still, the CORS error occurs.

Comment: Could you please send both request and response headers by deleting your API key areas? And I am not sure but beforehand you can also try to change "bearer " to "Bearer ", and also you have a typo in your headers "Autherization" -> "Authorization".

Comment: Actually with the same code I am getting response in Postman I don't know whats happening here